# users in array , send sms to them

Tags: php, arrays

this code is my API SMS PANEL :

```
    <?php
require_once('./api_send_sms.php');
if (($result = Send_SMS('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', '100002972', 'USERNUMBER', 'Hello World!', 0, false)) === '0')
{
    echo 'SMS sent successfully.';
}
else if ($result !== '')
{
    echo "Error No: $result";
}
?>
```

and here i have this user codes :

```
$users = array(
  array('username' => 'user1','mobile' => '0000000000'),
  array('username' => 'user2','mobile' => '0000000000'),
);
```

i want to send sms to all of them with this messeage "username message has been sent" , how can i ?
regards

Comment: Link to SMS sending API please.

Comment: @Justinas there is api_send_sms.php file !  and included !

Comment: guys i have sms panel ! i don't want use anything free ! i paid for that !

Comment: Yes, you included, but where on internet is that? I don't have your API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
require_once('./api_send_sms.php');
$users = array(
    array('username' => 'user1','mobile' => '0000000000'),
    array('username' => 'user2','mobile' => '0000000000'),
);

foreach($users as $value){
    $result = Send_SMS('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', '100002972', $value['mobile'], 'Hello World!', 0, false) ;
    if($result === 0){
        echo 'SMS sent successfully.';
    }elseif ($result != ''){
        echo "Error No: $result";
    }
}
```

Comment: Error On this line `    $result = Send_SMS('XXXX', 'XXX', '123321', $value['mobile'], 'Hello World!', 0, false)) ;
`

Comment: Updated the code: there was one extra bracket which was supposed to be removed

Comment: in big array we have Time-Out ! any solution ?

Comment: as I understand the timeout occurs because of SMS sending time. So in order not to have this kind of problem try to use AJAX in order to send SMS-s one by one, instead of going trough the all array at once.

Answer (score 2):

use a foreach:

```
foreach($users as $key => $user){
//send sms script
}
```

Because of lack of information,i cant give you a proper example,but i hope you get the idea

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Send_SMS()` method returns 0 on success

```
<?php
require_once('./api_send_sms.php');
$users = array(
               array('username' => 'user1','mobile' => '0000000000'),
               array('username' => 'user2','mobile' => '0000000000')
              );
foreach($users as $u)
{
    if (Send_SMS('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', '100002972', $u['mobile'], 'Hello World!', 0, false) == 0)
    {
        echo 'SMS sent successfully.';
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error on sending SMS to the user:" . $u['username'];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: in big array we have Time-Out ! any solution ?

Comment: This code has an error for 100%, as the variable `$result` is undefined.

Comment: @zkanoca, you still have it in `echo` and doing so will never show the error code...

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting your sendsms code into a single function and try to use for loop instantiating the send sms functioin every loop until all you have sent a sms in all users